# Netbeans Compiler Error in Wrong Place

Tags: netbeans, compiler-errors

I am new to Netbeans. Netbeans shows an error as below:

[image]

But the error text is: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to Vertex. I'm sure it's referring to the code below it that uses Vertex in many places, but the file is long and I have no idea which line to go to. Is there a way to fix this, or is this a bug, or am I interpreting everything wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Bug still there, but a workaround is to run the project and the compile error will show up in the output. I'm used to Eclipse where you normally can't run a project with complier errors. But this is a way to find the line.